# Wait till Captcha field filled with four numbers

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

This is not a try to overcome the captcha, I have coded the code so as to let the user type the captcha appears to him in the field of captcha

What I am trying to do but didn't find a way and stuck at it is that I would like to write waiting lines till the field of captcha is filled
so I tried such lines

```
Do
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Loop Until Len(.FindElementById("txtCaptcha").Text) = 4
```

But when debugging I didn't get the text of the element after I have typed some numbers in ..How can I achieve that point?

I have alternative solution is to set a line like that

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
```

That will wait for 10 seconds till the user type the numbers but I would like to wait using Do Loop Until ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in an iframe based on your other questions. Use the iframe `src` in the `.get` line. As you are using selenium the appropriate syntax is as shown below. `DoEvents` allows the user to input values.

```
Do
    DoEvents
Loop While Len(.FindElementById("txtCaptcha").Attribute("value")) < 4
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for great help. This works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

It must be the element value. try to get innerText or value in the browser console. Use document.querySelector("#txtCaptcha").value or document.querySelector("#txtCaptcha").innerText .

Comment: I am using Selenium in VBA and I tried .Text and tried Attribute("value") and nothing returns the value that the user typed ..I think this is a very good point but how to implement the `document.querySelector("#txtCaptcha").value` to use in the code